# Substitute dataset coordinates in xarray (Python)

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a dataset stored in NetCDF4 format that consists of `Intensity` values with 3 dimensions: `Loop`, `Delay` and `Wavelength`. I named my coordinates the same as the dimensions (I don't know if it's good or bad...)

I'm using **xarray** (formerly xray) in Python to load the dataset:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('test_data.netcdf4')
```

Now I want to manipulate the data while keeping track of the original data. For instance, I would:

1. Apply an offset to the `Delay` coordinates and keep the original `Delay` dataarray untouched. This seems to be done with:

   `ds_ = ds.assign_coords(Delay_corr=ds_.Delay.copy(deep=True) + 25)`
2. Substitute the coordinates `Delay` for `Delay_corr` for all relevant dataarrays in the dataset. However, I have no clue how to do this and I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Would anybody know how to perform item #2?

To download the NetCDF4 file with test data:
http://1drv.ms/1QHQTRy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method you're looking for is the [`xr.swap_dims()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.swap_dims.html) method:

```
ds.coords['Delay_corr'] = ds.Delay + 25  # could also use assign_coords
ds2 = ds.swap_dims({'Delay': 'Delay_corr'})
```

See [this section](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.7.1/data-structures.html#renaming-variables) of the xarray docs for a full example.

Comment: This swaps the dimensions, but doesn't update the coordinates correctly

Answer (score 4):

I think it's much simpler than that.

If you don't want to change the existing data, you create a copy. Note that changing `ds` won't change the netcdf4 file, but assuming you still don't want to change `ds`:

```
ds_ = ds.copy(deep=True)
```

Then just set the `Delay` coord as a modified version of the old one

```
ds_.coords['Delay'] = ds_['Delay'] + 25
```